# ORA-02437: "primary key violated" - why can't I see duplicate ID in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, constraints, primary-key, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would receive an error:

```
ORA-02437:  cannot validate  (%s.%s) - primary key violated
Cause:  attempted to validate a primary key with duplicate values or null values
```

I found it was because I have a stored procedure that increments the ID, but it had failed to do so when it re-ran and had an error related to one of my datatypes.  I found I now had a duplicate ID in my database table.  All this made sense and I was able to easily rectify it with a `DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID = x`, where `x` was the offending duplicate ID.  *The problem I have* is the only way I was able to even find the IDs that were duplicated is in the first place is because I did a `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = x` -- where `x` was one greater than the last ID I could actually see.  I found it just by an educated guess.  So:

1. Why can't I see these duplicate IDs when I open the table in Oracle SQL Developer?  It only shows the last row as the ID before the duplicates.  I don't think it is because of my primary key constraint, since the first line in my stored procedure is to remove that (and put it back, at the end - probably when I got my error), and it was not present when I looked at my table.
2. Is there some way to make these last IDs that got inserted into the table visible, so I wouldn't have to guess or assume that the duplicate IDs are "hiding" as one greater than the last ID I have in my table, in the future?  There is a `commit;` in my stored procedure, so they should have appeared -- unless, of course, the procedure got hung up before it could run that line of code (highly probable).

Stored procedure that runs:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE PRC_MYTABLE_INTAKE(
, EMPLOYEE_ID IN NVARCHAR2
, TITLE_POSITION IN NVARCHAR2
, CREATED_DATE IN DATE
, LAST_MODIFIED IN DATE
) AS
 myid integer := 0;
 appid integer := 0;
BEGIN
-- disable PK constraint so it can be updated
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MYTABLE DROP CONSTRAINT MYTABLE_PK';  
COMMIT;
-- assign ID to myid
SELECT ID INTO myid FROM MYTABLE WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM MYTABLE);
-- increment
myid := myid + 1;
-- assign APPLICATION_ID to appid
SELECT APPLICATION_ID INTO appid FROM MYTABLE WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM MYTABLE);
-- increment
appid := appid + 1;
-- use these ids to insert with
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, APPLICATION_ID, 
, EMPLOYEE_ID
, TITLE_POSITION
, CREATED_DATE
, LAST_MODIFIED
 ) VALUES(myid, appid, 
, EMPLOYEE_ID
, TITLE_POSITION
, CREATED_DATE
, LAST_MODIFIED
);
COMMIT;
-- re-enable the PK constraint
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE PASS ADD CONSTRAINT MYTABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)';
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: I don't understand - with SQL Developer (or any tool) you can see **all** rows in **any** table that you have `select` access to?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking.  All I can tell you is that if you have a primary key constraint defined on `ID`, there is no way you have duplicate `ID`s in your table.  Unless your definition of a *duplicate* is something else entirely.

Comment: The error he is getting - `ORA-02437` indicates that his stored procedure code is trying to add or enable the constraint on the fly.  If his code were just inserting duplicates, he'd get an `ORA-00001`.

Comment: @sstan, Again, my stored procedure removes the constraint in order to do an insertion to my table.  I can't insert at all with it there - dupe or not.  The error happens like Matt said, when I re-insert it at the end.  That's not really the problem - I understand why that happens.  The question revolves around why I can't see the duplicate entries in my table without doing a direct `SELECT` on IDs I can't see.

Comment: Perhaps VPD is being used and there are rows in the table you can't see due to security policy?  But then you wouldn't see them with a select on ID either.  This basically can't be happening as you describe it!

Comment: @TonyAndrews Account I'm using in SQL Developer has full-rights to this table.  I created the table using it.

Comment: Maybe your sql dev. tool do not fetch the entire table... My tool has a default defined limit (200) to avoid huge data retrieval (and time loss).

Comment: So if you do `select count(*)` from this table, is the number returned higher than the total number of rows you can actually fetch?

Comment: Then I think the more interesting question is why you can't insert with the constraint in place. Removing and readding a constraint on the fly doesn't sound like a great idea.  It can come in handy for performance reasons when you're inserting a batch of data, but otherwise, I'm not sure why you would need to do that,

Comment: @J.Chomel There's only 75 rows returned.  ID 76 gets duplicated.

Comment: So maybe your procedure is called twice? Or you have a logical issue? What about sharing the relevant code's part?

Comment: @sstan Yeah, I don't get that, either, but it's just what I had to do.  And yes, I've subsequently found that the procedure gets called (deliberately) onload of a page, and the problem arose when clicking a button that also runs it.  But I don't think that has to do with why the rows don't appear in the table when I open it.

Comment: @vapcguy: You're right, I don't think one thing is necessarily related to the other.  I'm just saying that if I had to ask a question on SO, I wouldn't pick this one.  I would want to know how to leave the constraint in place and have my code work correctly.  But that's just me.

Comment: Presumably you "had to do" it because the procedure tries to insert duplicate keys - so you have removed the constraint before inserting and obviously now have a duplicate?

Comment: The first thing that came to mind you already thought of. For you to see rows that were added to a table when you start SQL Developer, the transaction has to be committed. (Even if you open SQL Developer under the same user name; transactions are within sessions, and now you are in a different session.) It is indeed possible or likely that your procedure failed before it got to `commit`. In that case, if a row was in fact added but something else failed in the procedure, after the row was added but before `commit`, you would see the new row in the old session but not in the new one.

Comment: I suspect his stored procedure is encountering the `ORA-02437` error and issuing a rollback in response.  The reason he cannot see the offending duplicates is because they've been rolled back.  Hard to tell without code.

Comment: ... although that doesn't explain why you should be able to see it later, by "guessing" at the id. Perhaps something else happened in the meantime, and the transaction was committed at that point?

Comment: Posted the proc (sanitized... it has a lot of fields....).  No manual commits were made between running of the proc and when I checked SQL Developer to see the row (both through the Data tab of "MYTABLE" and running my `SELECT` query).  Only commits are those in the proc.  But that's probably why it doesn't show. Though doing a `COMMIT` like I just tried still doesn't make the duplicates appear - even without the constraint being there.

Comment: @mathguy I think you're exactly right.  The proc is being ran by an application, so when it fails, and doesn't commit anything, it's in that app's session - not mine.  So that explains my question #1.  If there just isn't a way to make it commit, if it fails, without adding a line to my `try... catch` in my app, well, maybe that's the answer to my question #2.  Of course, that could cause its own exception and wouldn't do that.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are about 13 instances of either bad practice, redundancy, or basic misunderstandings about the way that Oracle code ought to be written, in this procedure. Among them, note that a DDL statement issues two implicit commits itself, so all three of the explicit commits are redundant.

Comment: @DavidAldridge None of the commits are redundant.  I know from actually running the procedure.  I need each line to execute, and they weren't until I added those commands.  Maybe if Oracle worked as well as SQL does, I wouldn't've needed them, but because Oracle offers (as a feature!) the ability to rollback commands, it doesn't believe it's actually *done* them until the commit is done.  So I could be (later on in the procedure) trying to add back the constraint when it was never *actually* removed, and I was getting that as an error until I added the `commit`. Didn't do it for my health.

Comment: @vapcguy So take the commits out. The functionality will be exactly the same. A DDL statement starts with an implicit commit, does whatever it has to do, then issues a commit again. Always. You cannot rollback DDL in Oracle, and they always issue two commits. Guess what -- here's Tom Kyte saying so: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f? p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:7072180788422

Comment: @DavidAldridge Again, without the commits, when it goes to try to add the PK constraint back, it acts like it was never removed, and does not run.  The implicit commit, assuming you're right and it even did that, was not enough.  Run a proc for yourself to do what I did and you'll see, rather than busting my chops with documentation.  I have practical experience.

Comment: @vapcguy You do not need explicit commits for DDL to take place. Whatever problem you had, you misdiagnosed it.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Note that there are DML operations here, and DML *does* require commits, and doesn't issue them automatically.  For DDL, you should be correct, though I could swear I had errors without it - perhaps because of using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  The `INSERT`, itself, however, is DML and would require it.

Comment: @vapcguy Yes, DML requires commits, but executing the DDL operations provided those required commits as an Oracle DDL statement issues commits before and after execution. My point was that if all of the explicit `commit` commands were removed, the procedure would be functionally unchanged.

Comment: @DavidAldridge The later DDL commits don't help when there is a DML before it that stalls out the code.  The code doesn't always auto-advance to the next operation if there are errors.  And there is a `COMMIT;` after the `INSERT`. If the insert failed, the `COMMIT;` after it, and any other code after it, would not run.  Procedure-wise, yes, they don't make or break the end result if everything works correctly. It only comes into play when things break.

Comment: @vapcguy Hmmm well my point was that the `commit` after the insert is redundant, because there's automatically a commit as the first step in the subsequent `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ...`. Whether any step in the procedure raises an error or not, all three explicits `commit`s can be removed with no change in behaviour.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Again, ONLY if everything works properly, yes.  If any DML operation gets hung up, the rest doesn't fire. That's all I was trying to get you to admit/understand.  And for that matter, if a DDL operation after the `INSERT` and `COMMIT` gets hung up and errors, and the DML operation, like that `INSERT`, has no `COMMIT`, that information is not available to users-so the `COMMIT` is necessary if there are errors/the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement didn't run/work.  Agreed, if there are no problems, yes, it would be redundant.  But that line of thinking is what causes issues in debug.

Comment: @vapcguy OK, the only way that the `commit` after the `insert` becomes significant is if the subsequent DDL statement is syntactically invalid. If it parses and begins executing, the first thing it does is issue a `commit`. If it fails to add the constraint because ID is not unique or has a null value then that `commit` has still been executed. Of course if the DDL statement is not syntactically valid then it isn't a DDL statement, but maybe that's what you mean.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I'm thinking that maybe because the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement couldn't put back the constraint because it didn't find the constraint there, that this was enough to prevent an initial commit - since that's why I put in the `COMMIT`, to get the `INSERT` to show up, when I started seeing those errors on that.  I get that normally a DLL does a commit prior to running, but I just know it never did when it failed like that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one problem:

```
SELECT ID
INTO myid
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM MYTABLE)
```

There is no correlation between ID and ROWID, so you're not getting the maximum current ID, you're just getting the one that happens to be on the row that is furthest from the start of a datafile with a high number.

The code you need is:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID),0)
FROM   MYTABLE;
```

Or better yet, just use a sequence.

No idea why you're dropping the PK either.

Furthermore, when you issue the query:

```
SELECT APPLICATION_ID INTO appid ...
```

... that could be for a different row than the one you already got the id for, because a change could have been committed to the table.

Of course another issue is that you can't run two instances of this procedure at the same time either.

Comment: ID isn't an integer, was stored as `NVARCHAR`, so `COALESCE` doesn't work on it.  That code works to give me the last value on the last row entered, and allows it to be incremented.  I know it's not the "proper" way to do it, but it works for the types I'm dealing with.  Tried doing it with a `NUMBER` field and sequence, trigger, all that on another table, found I ended up having to drop it all just to do an insert.

Comment: Problem with why I have to drop the constraint is the same reason this guy also had the same error I did, before my dropping and re-adding of it on the fly -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472020/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-pk-address-etc-what-am-i-doing-wrong -- only I can't fix it like he did by just not specifying it.  I have to be sure it's incrementing, and insert a value to it.

Comment: While your comment about the `SELECT APPLICATION_ID INTO appid` not getting the same row might be valid in an Enterprise environment with thousands of users, this app will be used by less than 20 at a time, and likely not simultaneously.  Plus, the proc runs in milliseconds, so not worried about someone doing an insert at the same time as another.

Comment: Also, I'm not really concerned about the proc so much as to how to figure out which IDs are duplicated when it fails, and why they are hidden.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is exactly the problem.  The row with the `MAX(ROWID)` _isn't_ the row with the `MAX(ID)`, hence the duplicates.

Comment: "That code works to give me the last value on the last row entered" ... no, it doesn't I'm afraid. ROWID is not related to the order in which rows are entered except in the most loose sense. If ID is not an integer (why?) then you'll have to either use MAX(TO_NUMBER(ID)) or, better yet, use a sequence (the standard practice) and convert to NVARCHAR on insert.

Comment: "Also, I'm not really concerned about the proc so much as to how to figure out which IDs are duplicated when it fails, and why they are hidden." -- you are not selecting the highest ID. You are querying for a particular row based on its physical location in the database.

Comment: You can get excellent performance on MAX(TO_NUMBER(ID)) by adding an index on TO_NUMBER(ID)

Comment: @DavidAldridge Everyone keeps saying that `ROWID` isn't related to the order in which rows are entered, but that's a lie, so stop spreading it. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3Ap11_question_id:53140678334596 From AskTom:  `A rowid is assigned to a row upon insert and is imutable (never changing) unless the row is deleted and re-inserted (meaning it is another row, not the same row!)` The table I'm using is NOT going to have any deletions to it. In my case, the last row inserted IS going to be the highest ID in my table. There will NEVER be a case when it isn't.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I had issues where I could not insert on a table when I had a sequence and trigger added to it, so making it a number doesn't help when I'd just have to remove all of that and add it back on the fly, just like I'm having to do with the PK constraint.  If you can explain why I can't do insertions via a stored procedure with a trigger/sequence attached, I'm all ears, but no one else seemed to have this problem on the net. I could do `MAX(TO_NUMBER(ID))` but really, none of that had to do with why I couldn't see the duplicate records or help with being able to see them.

Comment: @vapcguy "Everyone keeps saying that ROWID isn't related to the order in which rows are entered" because it's true. Tom Kyte demonstrates it here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:912210644860. It doesn't matter if there are deletions or not because inserted rows do not always go at the end of the physical table -- it's in the documentation. Everyone also says to manage PK assignment with an integer and a sequence, but I can't guess at why you couldn't make it work. You are definitely not "all ears" either. Sorry, but your code is awful.

Comment: @DavidAldridge `Every record has a unique ROWID within a database representing the physical location on disk where the record lives...ROWID's will change when you reorganize or export/import a table.` http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ROWID What you and others keep spreading is a fundamental misunderstanding.  You automatically assume rows will be reorganized, exported, deleted.  In my particular table, the only thing done to it is the insertion and updating of records.  No deletions, no exports, no reorganization.

Comment: @DavidAldridge  As for making a table work where I can insert a record where it has a sequence (which then requires a trigger to make it work), you get mutating trigger issues when trying to do inserts/updates:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o58asktom-101055.html -- among other errors I was getting.  Wasn't worth it.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak My update using `ROWID` has nothing to do with the duplicates at all.  The code increments the ID like it's supposed to *IF* it completes.  The problem was a type mismatch I had in the variables I was passing in that kept it from completing.  The code, for how I'm using it, against the column I'm using it against, is actually fine and does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @vapcguy So no new extent will be allocated with a block number lower than any previous block used for that data segment? Because if that does happen, you now have ROWIDs lower than the maximum because that's how ROWIDs are constructed -- data object number:block:row:file https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i46148 You're relying on every extent having a higher block number than every other.

Comment: @vapcguy You get mutating trigger errors when you try to read the table that is being modified. You don't need to do that when you're just assigning a value from a sequence, so whatever problem you had was nothing to do with sequences or integers.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Because there are never any deletes to this table, there would never be a reallocation of previous blocks, by definition.  It can only go forward.  I took that into account, but I do appreciate the wisdom.

Comment: @vapcguy Still got to look out for new extents being created in a different file, or earlier in the same file, though I'm afraid. I also seem to recall that ASSM can spread inserts over a number of blocks that are tagged as having free space, so I would not be sure that they even advance in position within an extent. Please don't try relying on them for insert order -- they will break both your code and your heart.

Answer (score 0):

For David Aldridge, since he wants to look at code instead of the real reason I posted my question, run this ---

```
CREATE TABLE YOURSCHEMA.TESTING 
(
  TEST_ID NVARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
, TEST_TYPE NVARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT TEST_PK PRIMARY KEY 
 (
    TEST_ID
 )
 ENABLE 
);

create or replace 
PROCEDURE PRC_TESTING_INSERT(
  TEST_TYPE IN NVARCHAR2
) AS
  testid integer := 0;
BEGIN
-- disable PK constraint so it can be updated
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TESTING DROP CONSTRAINT TEST_PK';  
COMMIT;
-- assign TEST_ID to testid
SELECT TEST_ID INTO testid FROM TESTING WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM TESTING);
-- increment
testid := testid + 1;
-- use this id to insert with
INSERT INTO TESTING (TEST_ID, TEST_TYPE) VALUES(testid, TEST_TYPE);
COMMIT;
-- re-enable the PK constraint
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TESTING ADD CONSTRAINT TEST_PK PRIMARY KEY (TEST_ID)';
COMMIT;
END;

SET serveroutput on;
DECLARE
    test_type varchar(100);
BEGIN
   test_type := 'dude';
   YOURSCHEMA.PRC_TESTING_INSERT(test_type);
   -- to verify the variable got set and procedure ran, could do:
   --dbms_output.enable;
   --dbms_output.put_line(test_type);
END;
```

Now, because there is no data in the table, the stored procedure will fail with `ORA-06512: no data found`.  If you then try and run it again, you will get `ORA-02443: cannot drop constraint - nonexistent constraint`, because the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TESTING DROP CONSTRAINT TEST_PK';` successfully dropped it, and the procedure never ran the command at the end to re-add it.  This is what made me think I needed the commits, but even without them, it still will not complete the whole procedure.

To prove that the procedure DOES run, if given proper data, run this after creating the table, but before creating/running the stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO TESTING (TEST_ID, TEST_TYPE)
VALUES ('1', 'hi');
```

And if you run the proc from a new table (not one with its constraint dropped), it will run fine.

Comment: The presence or absence of the explicit commits has nothing to do with the procedure completing or not. An error was raised, and even if the procedure rolled back it would only do so as far as the last commit, which would be the implicit one at the end of the DDL that dropped the constraint. Hence the constraint stayed dropped. And all three of those explicit commits *are* completely redundant. And you only needed this shockingly over-complex code because you inexplicably could not get the 100% standard practice sequence-based PK method working.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Do you even read what I write before you comment?  I already admitted the `COMMIT` statements didn't matter; simply proving a point that there are **NOT** so-called *implicit* commits that just ALWAYS run. If the procedure fails, commands can fail if they depend on those later statements running (like when a PK is dropped, but never replaced, then code is re-ran and tries to drop it again). And yes, already admitted I needed this code because I couldn't get it to insert if I had a sequence/trigger on the table. Just think I've proven you can't rely on it to do cleanup for you.

Comment: Well I guess we're getting somewhere, since you previously wrote that "None of the commits are redundant.". To me, "didn't matter" equals "redundant". "Just think I've proven you can't rely on it to do cleanup for you." means that a rollback doesn't restore a dropped constraint, so yes that's true. Why is it true? Because inherent in the DDL that dropped the constraint are two commits. This isn't me being harsh on you, it's me making sure that anyone who comes across this in future doesn't walk away thinking "Oh you need to COMMIT after executing DDL in Oracle!", which is incorrect.

Comment: Why don't you just throw all this away and get that sequence-based method working?

Comment: @DavidAldridge No, "didn't matter" just meant they weren't all getting called. And actually what I was saying, or trying to say, was affirming you all along, that yes, the commits I later found to be unnecessary-the removing the PK always happened, the adding it back, which was really the problem, never would, if it failed mid-stream.  I had the sequence/trigger all working on just a blank table at one point, problem was trying to insert a record to the table with a trigger still in place, and just wasted a day on it, so took the table I was given and worked around it.  Agreed, not ideal.

Answer (score -1):

Since mathguy didn't post this as the answer, though I'll credit him for the information...

Answer to why I can't see the duplicates is because the `COMMIT` does not occur in the procedure when it failed due to a datatype mismatch (which we found was actually in the application's code that sent the variable's values into this procedure, not in the stored procedure, itself).  (It's also why I'll mark down anyone that says you don't have to add so many `COMMIT` lines in this procedure.) The commands were run in the session of the user that starts it - in my case, another session of the same DB user I was logged in with, but started from my application, instead of my SQL Developer session.  It also explains why I could do a `COMMIT`, myself, but it did not affect the application's session - I could not commit any actions ran from another session.  Had I ran a `COMMIT` as an `OracleCommand` and did an `.ExecuteNonQuery` on my `OracleConnection` right after the failure within the `catch` of my application, I would have seen the rows in SQL Developer without having to do a special query.

So, in short, the only way to see the items was with a direct query using `WHERE ID =`, find the last ID and increment it, and put it in the query.

Comment: I'm down voting this because an Oracle DDL statement starts and ends with a commit. Even if the DDL fails, the initial commit has taken effect. It's in the documentation -- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm I would be very happy to retract this if anyone can come up with a demonstration that disproves it.

Comment: So you're sticking with your position that in some unstated circumstances, execution of Oracle DDL does not implicitly issue two commits? You've looked for reputable evidence to support that claim, and you haven't found any, right? And you can't demonstrate it with a simple script that shows DDL being rolled-back, for example. Sorry, but you're just completely wrong on this.

Comment: @DavidAldridge See my example.  It will only run a procedure up to the point of failure.  Anything after that doesn't get run.  But NONE of this codetalk has ANYTHING to do with my question, or this answer, so you shouldn't be voting any of this down.  I voted yours down since it had nothing to do with my question, and I had tried `COALESCE` before and once I added a trigger, it was just downhill from there.

Comment: "It will only run a procedure up to the point of failure. Anything after that doesn't get run" -- Obviously so. The relevance of this to your problem is that you only have that problem because you are trying to achieve something in a completely bizarre and non-standard manner, with a huge logical flaw in it. Even your point about Coalesce -- that it "doesn't work" on NVARCHARs -- was wrong.

Comment: @DavidAldridge `COALESCE` **does** require a number - just I didn't think, at the time, to put `SELECT COALESCE(MAX(TO_NUMBER(ID)), 0) FROM MYTABLE`.  Emphasis on **TO_NUMBER** in order to handle an NVARCHAR2 field value.  I know normally this would not have been required, and at the time I was still pretty new to Oracle and didn't know it required this stuff.

Comment: @DavidAldridge So it took a year for me to figure this whole `COMMIT` issue out. Yes, there are implicit commits on DDL operations (tables getting created/dropped/altered, sequence/trigger getting created, etc.), BUT there are NOT implicit commits on DML operations (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`), such as the `INSERT` statement this procedure was doing. So while my answer was not explicit, it really **IS** because of the `INSERT` command having an error that its `COMMIT` never ran. Having THAT `COMMIT` really **was** necessary for an outside user to see the inserts, if they succeeded.